# Pegar a primeira e última inserção de um usuário

Tags: mysql

Estou com a seguinte query:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/431414/1)

A questão é o seguinte. Nessa tabela há diversas interações de vários usuários em uma mesma transação. O que eu preciso é pegar o tempo de duração do último usuário na transação.

Por exemplo:

De acordo com a tabela acima, o idusers 560049 foi o último usuário a atender a transação. Ele iniciou o atendimento às 2018-09-12T09:34:50Z e encerrou o atendimento às 2018-09-12T09:54:50Z. O tempo de atendimento neste caso é de 20 minutos.

O que importa pra mim é sempre o último usuário da transação.

Se eu tentar colocar o min e o max dá problema porque ele agrupa e fica errado.

E se for o caso do usuário não ter um tempo fim, quero apenas ignorá-lo. Como no exemplo abaixo:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ce93f/3)

Sei que a pergunta tá complexa, mas eu não consegui explicar de outra forma. Caso algum moderador ache que não está clara, me avise que tento reformular a questão.

Comment: Um `ORDER BY` com `LIMIT 1` não resolveria? `select * from obusuario
order by created desc limit 1` ?

Comment: Não, porque eu preciso pegar o tempo de atendimento. Ou seja, a primeira inserção e a última. :)

Comment: Tenta assim: `SELECT idusers, MIN(created), MAX(created)
FROM obusuario
WHERE idusers IN (SELECT idusers FROM obusuario
ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1)`

Comment: Deu esse erro: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: Executou no seu banco? Porque no fiddle é bloqueado LIMIT em subquery

Comment: Sim, foi no meu banco. Estou usando o dbeaver. E preciso que essa informação seja exibida no bi do metabase, e deu o mesmo erro lá tbm. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer (que deu certo devido limites do MySQL), seria por *subquery*:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT idusers, MIN(created) mn, MAX(created) mx 
FROM obusuario 
GROUP BY idusers 
ORDER BY MAX(created)) tab 
ORDER BY mx DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Certíssimo. Thanks. :)